# How to achieve pagination in Android using jQuery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have seen some demos about the jQuery wizard plugin on websites. But all of these are based on the web, and run in the browser.

I want to use this function in my Android application, does anyone has experience with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to convert a web app to an Android native app. See also some of our [demos](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/included-demo-apps), [videos](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/download/demos-and-tutorials) and [tutorials](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials). Many of them demonstrate native Android apps built with jQuery Mobile.